# What is different between navigator and navigatorIOS in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Just look through fb's document.

What is different between navigator and navigatorIOS in react-native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigator is a transition between different scenes in your app, it can be regarded as an animation.

NavigatorIOS wraps UIKit navigation, it will push or pop a controller and behave more like an Native navigation.

Answer (score 3):

There used to be a comparision between the two in the official docs. Not sure why it is removed since 0.31. You can still get it from google the cached version though:

> Navigator Comparison
>
> The differences between Navigator and NavigatorIOS are a common source
>   of confusion for newcomers.
>
> Both Navigator and NavigatorIOS are components that allow you to
>   manage the navigation in your app between various "scenes" (another
>   word for screens). They manage a route stack and allow you to pop,
>   push, and replace states. In this way, they are similar to the html5
>   history API. The primary distinction between the two is that
>   NavigatorIOS leverages the iOS UINavigationController class, and
>   Navigator re-implements that functionality entirely in JavaScript as a
>   React component. A corollary of this is that Navigator will be
>   compatible with Android and iOS, whereas NavigatorIOS will only work
>   on the one platform. Below is an itemized list of differences between
>   the two.
>
> Navigator #
>
> - Extensive API makes it completely customizable from JavaScript.
> - Under active development from the React Native team.
> - Written in JavaScript.
> - Works on iOS and Android.
> - Includes a simple navigation bar component similar to the default     NavigatorIOS bar: Navigator.NavigationBar, and another with
>     breadcrumbs called Navigator.BreadcrumbNavigationBar.
> - See the UIExplorer demo to try them out and see how to use them.    Currently animations are good and improving, but they are still less
>     refined than Apple's, which you get from NavigatorIOS.
> - You can provide your own navigation bar by passing it through the    navigationBar prop.
>
> NavigatorIOS #
>
> - Small, limited API makes it much less customizable than Navigator in    its current form.
> - Development belongs to open-source community - not used by the React    Native team on their apps. A result of this is that there is 
>     currently a backlog of unresolved bugs, nobody who uses this has
>     stepped up to take ownership for it yet.
> - Wraps UIKit, so it works exactly the same as it would on another    native app. Lives in Objective-C and JavaScript. Consequently, you
>     get the animations and behaviour that Apple has developed. iOS only.
> - Includes a navigation bar by default; this navigation bar is not a    React Native view component and the style can only be slightly
>     modified.

Based on my experience, navigatorIOS is pretty buggy for now and I would suggest using Navigator instead. If you take a look at the Facebook F8 app, they were using Navigator rather than navigatorIOS.

Comment: You can also find the information in an older release i.e. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.26/docs/navigator-comparison.html#content